# SQL Server Express - silent installation ends on unsupported language

Tags: sql-server, cmd, silent-installer

I'm using command `SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`
to install SQL Server 2019 Express.
The installation ends with:

```
Your language čeština (Česko) (cs-CZ) is not supported. Continue in English?

See this for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/sql-server/install/local-language-versions-in-sql-server

For more information use /? or /Help.
```

I found parameter `/ENU`

*Use this parameter to install the English version of SQL Server on a localized operating system when the installation media includes language packs for both English and the language corresponding to the operating system.*

No matter what combination I choose the installation will end the same.
I've tried so far:

```
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=true
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=True
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=false
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=False

SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU="true"
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU="True"
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU="false"
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU="False"

SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=0
SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU=1
```

What am I missing? How to proceed english installation without end-user interaction?

Comment: Maybe providing params as [configuration file](https://brycematheson.io/how-to-perform-a-silent-install-of-sql-server-or-sql-express/) will change anything

Comment: I don't think the `/ENU` switch applies to the downloader. I don't have a cs-CZ Windows so I haven't tried this, but you could probably make it work with `SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /Action=Download /MediaType=LocalDB /Quiet` followed up with `msiexec.exe /qb /i %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\en-US\SqlLocalDB.msi IAcceptSqlLocalDBLicenseTerms=YES /ENU`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [AlwyasLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) I figured a solution:

1. execute `SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe /Action=Download /MediaType=Core`, `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` will be downloaded
2. run `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` manunaly, just to extract to subfolder `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU`
3. from the subfolder `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU` execute `SETUP.EXE /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ENU /Action=Install`